# Configure test network file

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node

I am trying `Simulate Parachain` tutorial, in [configure the test network settings](https://docs.substrate.io/test/simulate-parachains/#configure-the-test-network-settings), there is step to create a configuration file `config.toml`. Can we create that file in any directory or should we need to include inside polkadot or parachain-template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store this configuration file wherever you want, then when you run the zombienet program you can specify the route, for example:

```
./zombienet-linux -p native spawn ./your-dir/config.toml
```

As an example check this repository: [Trappist](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist) where is has a folder zombientet with all the .toml configurations files, separate from the runtime files.